# TheIntern test framework asynchronous setup

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo, intern

As part of my project I am using https://github.com/theintern/intern/ to run unit and functional tests.

In one of my tests I am testing the server implementation of the JSON Rest API. I need this implementation to work with the Dojo JSON Rest client (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html).

Therefore I am trying to manually trigger the XHRs that Dojo Store is supposed to do. However, I do not know how to get around the CSRF protection in the browser since I could not find a way to integrate my server implementation (that I wish to test) with the web server found inside the Intern framework.

Intern webserver runs at `http://localhost:9000` and my JSON Rest Store is at `http://localhost:3000`, hence CSRF browser protection triggers.

Normally the page needing to do XHR across servers needs some sort of CSRF token/cookie authorization from the original server. How can I perform this with the Intern?
If I need to obtain this authorization from the JSON REST API server implementation, then my server won't be work as a **REST** implementation because I need to track state. Am I getting this right?

In my application proper (production server) this is not a problem because the server implementation of the JSON Rest API is also serving the static HTML page that initiates the XHR.

**UPDATE**:
I've found a guide about stateless CSRF protection: http://appsandsecurity.blogspot.de/2012/01/stateless-csrf-protection.html.
Still I need to test this and see how it applies to Dojo JSON Rest stores.

Comment: Why the down vote? Could someone explain what have I done wrong in my post - at least not to repeat the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard you can disable CSRF protections in some browsers, if you need that for development. However, that protection is a very crucial thing, without it AJAX requests would be too dangerous to allow the pages to use them...

Your both web application and REST channel must be on the **same IP** and **same port**. If you have 2 separate servers, the way to achieve it is using a **proxy server**. Either one of the servers offer such functionality, or you use the third (like Apache) to proxy calls to both servers.

I'm using Apache HTTPD with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). I store the client code (html and js) on apache, and I redirect the calls to rest services using config defined in `httpd.conf`:

```
ProxyPass /myapp/rest/ http://l0calhost:9000/myapp/rest/
```

Your rest channel will be availabe them (if your apache server listens on `l0calhost:3000`) under `http://l0calhost:3000/myapp/rest`, and the application (JS) can refer to it under /myapp/rest.

of course, you need first to uncomment the lines activating the mod_proxy

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Comment: Apache as a proxy doesn't help - for one I am using Node and do not wish to insert Apache even in my test environment. Also I'm not sure how to start/stop the proxy together with my test instances (Intern web server and REST API server). This could be relevant though to people using Apache anyway.

Comment: Well, you need to use at least proxy-able server.